# Java: Treemap - forbid null?

Tags: java, null, treemap

Is there a way to prevent a treemap from accepting null values, or do I need to do a check every time I enter something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write up a delegating Set that wraps the real Set and add a guard to Set.add().

If you are providing a Comparator to the TreeSet you can also complain if either of thw two inputs to the Comparator are null.

Answer (score 10):

```
public class NonNullTreeMap<K,V> extends TreeMap<K,V> {
    @Override
    public V put(K k, V v) {
         if (v == null) {
             throw new NullPointerException("value is null");
         }
         return super.put(k,v);
    }
}
```

You could also throw an IllegalArgumentException, but a NullPointerException is most appropriate IMO.

Note that it is **incorrect** to return `null` instead of throwing an exception.  The `java.util.Map` API states that the result of the `put` operation is the previous value of the mapping for `k`, or `null` if `k` was not previously mapped.

Comment: @akf: like I said ... it's a matter of opinion :-)